# Where can I find download history of Internet Explorer?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer

Is there any way to get Downloads history of IE?

We get Downloads history of Firefox from downloads.sqlite file and we get download history of Chrome from history.sqlite file.

But how to find out in IE?

Did some tryout with FindFirstUrlCacheEntry() but output is not as expected.
Read about index.dat file, but it is not updated as I browse in IE.

Comment: This would be a better question for superuser.com.

Comment: This is not off topic. He is programmatically looking for a solution. Down vote him for lack of example code but not to close as not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Use COM interface called IUrlHistoryStg.

```
int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    IUrlHistoryStg* ieHistory = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUrlHistory, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IUrlHistoryStg, (LPVOID *)(&ieHistory));

    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
        return 1;

    IEnumSTATURL* urlEnumer;
    hr = ieHistory->EnumUrls(&urlEnumer);

    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
        return 2;

    if (!SUCCEEDED(urlEnumer->SetFilter(L"", STATURL_QUERYFLAG_ISCACHED|STATURL_QUERYFLAG_TOPLEVEL|STATURL_QUERYFLAG_NOURL|STATURL_QUERYFLAG_NOTITLE|STATURLFLAG_ISTOPLEVEL|STATURLFLAG_ISCACHED)))
        return 4;

    if (!SUCCEEDED(urlEnumer->Reset()))
        return 3;

    unsigned long correct = 0;
    STATURL result = {};

    struct Urls
    {
        std::wstring url;
        std::wstring title;

        Urls(LPWSTR url, LPWSTR title) : url(url ? url : L""), title(title ? title : L"")
        {}
    };

    std::vector<Urls> urls;

    do
    {
        result.cbSize = sizeof(result);
        if (SUCCEEDED(urlEnumer->Next(1, &result, &correct)))
        {
            Urls url(result.pwcsUrl, result.pwcsTitle);
            urls.push_back(url);
        }
    } 
    while (correct == 1);

    size_t size = urls.size();
    ieHistory->Release();
    urlEnumer->Release();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried the above code and I can fetch the IR history i.e. links I have visited. However I can not track files I have downloaded. Also use of FindFirstUrlCacheEntry mentioned in the question results into urls I have visited. I want to fetch the history of downloaded files from Internet Explorer.